# Array values returns null

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am making post request with ajax and sending data with json format.Then I am fetching json with php and decode it into an array.When I print out whole array there is no problem. I can see the key value pairs.But when I try to print out this array's one of index value it returns null.What could be the problem?Here is my ajax request

```
$(function() {
    $("#del").click(function() {
        var file_id = 32
        var file_update = 1321321

        var obj = {
            file_id: file_id,
            file_update: file_update
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "config/ajax.php",
            data: {
                "file_update": JSON.stringify(obj)
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Here is my php code

```
if (isset($_POST["file_update"])) {
    $file_update = json_decode($_POST["file_update"], true);
    $x = $file_update[0];
    var_dump($x);
    var_dump($file_update);
}
```

Comment: It should be either `$file_update['file_id']` or `$file_update['file_update']`

Comment: Why are you using JSON? Just use `data: obj` and then you can use `$_POST['file_id']` and `$_POST['file_update']`.

Comment: thank you @Barmar it worked.I didn't think that I can send obj directly to php

Comment: `{"file_update": JSON.stringify(obj)}` is an object, isn't it? What's the difference between that and `obj`?

Answer (score 0):

The `$file_update` array is associative, therefore it doesn't have integer keys, its keys are **strings**.

`$file_update[0]` does not exist and this statement should throw an error given you have proper error reporting configured.

If you want to access specific array values use:

```
$file_update['file_id'];
$file_update['file_update'];
```

If you want to access the first element of an associative array you can use the following:

```
$key = array_keys($file_update)[0];
$value = $file_update[$key];
```

Comment: thanks a lot.It's my mistake you are right:)